# How to install graphicsmagick with freetype support in heroku?

Tags: heroku, graphicsmagick, buildpack

I'm trying to get GraphicsMagick to work on a heroku-20 stack, but am running into issues.

All the buildpacks I could find either were not working on the 20 stack, or if they did, they didn't include freetype support.

My "best try" was using

- `https://github.com/bogini/heroku-buildpack-graphicsmagick`
- `https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-apt`

to get at least the `gm` command to work, however, when trying to apply some text on an image, i run into this error:

```
 Error: Command failed: gm convert: FreeType library is not available (/usr/share/fonts/type1/gsfonts/n019003l.pfb) [No such file or directory].
```

Did anyone manage to get this working, or point me to how could I approach this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced the same problem. And finally, I solved the problem and now the gm library is working perfectly.

First, you should make your Heroku stack be: **Heroku-18**

by run this in terminal

```
$ heroku stack:set heroku-18
```

Second, you should add these two Buildpack in Heroku:

```
https://github.com/DuckyTeam/heroku-buildpack-imagemagick

https://github.com/xerpa/heroku-buildpack-graphicsmagick.git
```

like this:
[image]
**Note: The order is important**

---

---

The final Heroku project settings must be like this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for that! Just a side-note: heroku-18 is going to be supported until April 2023 https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-18-stack#support-period :)

Comment: Yes, You Are Right!